# door protector arduino program

Tags: programming, gsm

Please check the arduino program given below and help me to find out error.
The program is for following hardware.
GSM 800 module
Arduino Uno board
Limit switch(2)

We place two limit switch at main door & back door as main door is open the message will be send that is Main door is open & when it closed it will send message Main door is closed. This is same for Back door also.

We run this program & it run but it sends the massage repeatedly after some time.
Please help me to find out error..

***my ARDUINO code is***

```
const int Main = 7;
const int Store = 8;
const int Main_led =  13;
const int Store_led =  14;
bool i = true;
bool j = true;
bool k = true;
bool l = true;
int buttonState1 = 0;
int buttonState2 = 0;
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(Main_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Store_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Main, INPUT);
  pinMode(Store, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState1 = digitalRead(Main);
  if (buttonState1 == HIGH && i == true ) {
    digitalWrite(Main_led, HIGH);
    Serial.println("OK");
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"+91-------------");
    Serial.print("\"\r\n");
    delay(5000);
    Serial.print("Main Door is closed");
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(5000);
    i = false;
    j = true;
  }
  else
  { if (buttonState1 == LOW && j == true )

    { digitalWrite(Main_led, LOW);
      Serial.println("OK");
      delay(1000);
      Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
      delay(500);
      Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
      Serial.print("+91---------------");
      Serial.print("\"\r\n");
      delay(5000);
      Serial.print("Main Door is open");
      Serial.write(0x1A);
      delay(5000);
      i = true;
      j = false;
    }
  }

  buttonState2 = digitalRead(Store);
  if (buttonState2 == HIGH && k == true) {

    digitalWrite(Store_led, HIGH);
    Serial.println("OK");
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
    Serial.print("+91-------------");
    Serial.print("\"\r\n");
    delay(5000);
    Serial.print("Store room is Closed");
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(5000);
    k = false;
    l = true;
  }
  else
  { if (buttonState2 == LOW && l == true)
    {
      digitalWrite(Store_led, LOW);
      Serial.println("OK");
      delay(1000);
      Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
      delay(500);
      Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
      Serial.print("+91------------------");
      Serial.print("\"\r\n");
      delay(5000);
      Serial.print("Store room is Open");
      Serial.write(0x1A);
      delay(5000);
      k = true;
      l = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `it sends the massage repeatedly after some time` Which message? How long is `some time` is it after a certain number of button presses? after 5 minutes of nothing happening?

Comment: it is not depends on time but when switch is close(Door closed)(NC) it not repeated but when switch is open(door open)(NO) it send message repeatedly

Comment: You should be ashamed of yourself.  Writing code with no comment is irresponsible enough, but asking others to look at it is downright rude.  -1, and closing for the nearest handy reason  because this gross disrespect doesn't deserve a answer.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Are you telling a grown man to be ashamed of himself? The code is readable enough. +1 to OP because this isn't a forum for shame.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any obvious flaws in the code other than the excessive use of delay. However you could make your code a lot cleaner which makes it easier to spot the errors.
The version below has the duplicate lines moved into a function and instead of using the poorly named i,j,k & l to track two states it uses two variables to do the same job. Finally things that don't need to be global have been moved to being local.

```
const int Main = 7;
const int Store = 8;
const int Main_led =  13;
const int Store_led =  14;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(Main_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Store_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Main, INPUT);
  pinMode(Store, INPUT);
}

void sendMessage(char *text) {
    Serial.println("OK");
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"+91-------------");
    Serial.print("\"\r\n");
    delay(5000);
    Serial.print(text);
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(5000);
}

void loop() {
  static int oldState1 = -1;
  static int oldState2 = -1;

  int buttonState1 = digitalRead(Main);
  if (buttonState1 != oldState1) {
    digitalWrite(Main_led, buttonState1);
    if (buttonState1 == HIGH)
      sendMessage("Main Door is closed");
    else
      sendMessage("Main Door is open");
    oldState1 = buttonState1;
  }

  int buttonState2 = digitalRead(Store);
  if (buttonState2 != oldState2) {
    digitalWrite(Store_led, buttonState2 );
    if (buttonState2 == HIGH)
      sendMessage("Store room is closed");
    else
      sendMessage("Store room is open");
    oldState2 = buttonState2;
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to send Same message on two numbers how should I done

Comment: You should probably post another question giving enough detail to answer it. `I want to send Same message on two numbers` What numbers? In what situation?